# Json.net doesn't populate properties with default values when defined in the constructor

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

While migrating from JSON.Net 6 to latest version (9.0.1), I noticed a change of behavior regarding how DefaultValueHandling.Populate & IgnoreAndPopulate are handled during deserialization. With latest version, the Json property is initialized to null instead of its default value after deserialization.

Here is a simple test to reproduce the issue:

```
private class MyTestClass
{
    public const string DefaultText = "...";

    [DefaultValue(DefaultText)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myText", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public readonly string Text;

    public MyTestClass(string text = DefaultText)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

[Test]
public void DumbTest()
{
    MyTestClass myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTestClass>("{}"); // Fail with version 9.0.1
    Assert.AreEqual(MyTestClass.DefaultText, myObject.Text);
}
```

This happens because the constructor's argument name matches the property name. Therefore Json.net is now considering it as initialized by the constructor and is no longer applying the "default value handling" rule. This seems to come from this update of the library : [link](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/7e04b45894b3c1d43387a2f83202a9c06910938c).

Renaming the constructor's argument name to not match the propertie's name fixes my issue but it doesn't seem like a clean solution. Is there some configuration attribute I am missing (or cleaner way around)? I need the constructor because I want to be able to create the object myself (not from JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the change from Json 6.0.8 to 9.0.1.  It appears that [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1979) now checks for the presence of the `[DefaultValue(DefaultText)]` and `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]` attributes on the *constructor parameter* rather than the corresponding property.  This check is made around line 1979:

```
if (HasFlag(constructorProperty.DefaultValueHandling.GetValueOrDefault(Serializer._defaultValueHandling), DefaultValueHandling.Populate))
{
    context.Value = EnsureType(
        reader,
        constructorProperty.GetResolvedDefaultValue(),
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        constructorProperty.PropertyContract,
        constructorProperty.PropertyType);
}
```

Thus you can deserialize your type successfully by modifying the constructor as follows:

```
class MyTestClass
{
    public const string DefaultText = "...";

    [DefaultValue(DefaultText)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myText", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public readonly string Text;

    public MyTestClass([JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate), DefaultValue(DefaultText)] string text = DefaultText)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is an intentional or unintentional change.  You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) to ask.  Or perhaps you [already have](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1199)?

**Update**

As another workaround, you could give your type a private parameterless constructor that sets the default value correctly, and mark it with [`[JsonConstructor]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm):

```
class MyTestClass
{
    public const string DefaultText = "...";

    [DefaultValue(DefaultText)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myText", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public readonly string Text;

    [JsonConstructor]
    MyTestClass()
        : this(DefaultText)
    {
    }

    public MyTestClass(string text = DefaultText)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

Json.NET will now call the private parameterless constructor, then correctly set the value for the readonly field `Text` through reflection, since it has been marked with [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).  (Or even make the parameterless constructor public and make the parameter to the second constructor non-optional.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I reported [this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1199) while investigating and it looks like the root cause is now identified. Some workaround are possible but it definitely looks like a bug to me then